# Docker style Java command line parser

Tags: java, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

Very often I find myself writing CLI applications in Java which allow the user to perform a few tasks and many times I find each task has it's own specific flag.

For example:

java -jar myjar.jar send [...]
java -jar myjar.jar receive  [...]

Where send and receive would each have their own flags (Maybe some shared as well).

I have used jewelcli in the past but that only does global flags and so does commons-cli (Plus it's way too verbose). I suppose one could leverage these existing libraries but I was hoping someone has already given that some thought.

Is there command line parser which allows me to write a docker-like CLI applications in Java?

Comment: Why did 3 people mark this to be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at Argparse4j:

http://argparse4j.sourceforge.net/

Then you can use for example:

`java argument`

or even

`java argument -flag`

Comment: That looks like it is exactly what I was looking for, thank you